# Regex that matches certain characters and single wildcard

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that finds certain characters in a string and one wildcard (or any other given number of wildcard characters).

Characters can be any letter **a-z**, as do wildcards.

So far I have: `^[poe]+$`

My intension with the regex above is to match any word of any length containing ONLY the letters `poe` AND optionally *one* other letter. Some 'words' that could match:

- PPEEOX
- PO
- POX
- EEP

But not match:

- PPPXY
- XYP

Comment: Can you add some sample matching and non matching inputs?

Comment: Please provide some example matches

Comment: You say "should match words containing these letters and ONE other letter"  Does that mean a matching word has those three letters and the other or that the string as a whole does?  You say in a string earlier.

Comment: I've added some clarification

Comment: Try `\b(?=\w*[epo])[epo]*+[^\Wepo]?+[epo]*\b`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/gi7PQx/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assert that four characters appear in any order, then lookaheads might be one option here:

```
^(?=.*p)(?=.*o)(?=.*e)(?=.*q)[A-Za-z]{4,}$
```

This assumes that you want to match each of `poe`, as well as a fourth letter, `q`.

Comment: The letters POE can be in any order, and can each be in the word 0 times or more. The should be matches 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `?=` lookaheads to search for the specific letters and `\b` boundary to limit to 3-4 letters:

```
/\b(?=\w*p)(?=\w*o)(?=\w*e)[a-zA-Z]{3,4}\b/
```

Comment: You'd better replace `.*` with `\w*` otherwise it will match `ACDB` in `ACDB #$%poe`

Comment: @revo oh yeah. also added `^$` to match the whole string

Comment: If you add those anchors you don't need `\b`s. But as we don't know if OP is trying to match against whole input string or not, preferably it's okay to not have `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: i see. got it. I was just learning this regex thing this morning. I'm learning so much here in stackoverflow more than anywhere else, it's like working on an actual project with legit mentors.

Answer (score 0):

`[poe]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1}`

This means "There are [either one 'p' or 'o' or 'e']{appeared 3 times} and then [any alphabet]{appeared 1 time}", skipping the start mark and end mark.

Comment: Will also match "pppq" etc. not at least one each of p, o and e - assuming that is what the OP wants.

Comment: It also requires that the [poe] all  precede the fourth letter which doesn't appear to be a requirement. So "mope" is not a match.

Comment: let OP explain. This can be also assumed to be the expected answer, as long as no appropriate example provided from OP.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the characters of `[POE]` Should be in the string, `[POE]` can occur 0 or more times and the wildcard 0 or 1 times, you could use a positive lookahead and for the wildcard use a character class `[A-DF-NQ-Z]?` with a range that does not match a `P`, `O` or `E`:

```
^(?=.*[POE])[POE]*[A-DF-NQ-Z]?[POE]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQlqxj/1)

That will match

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=.*[POE])`
- `[POE]*` Match 0+ times a `P`, `O` or `E`
- `[A-DF-NQ-Z]?` Match an optional not `[POE]`
- `[POE]*` Match 0+ times a `P`, `O` or `E`
- `$` Assert the end of the line

Comment: This seems to work as you describe. But it only matches for example 'pose', while it should also match 'pos' for example. POE can be match 0 or more times. The wildcard 0 or 1 times.

Comment: @Stefan Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/tQlqxj/1/ Should it be upper or lowercase? I have updated my answer.